# My UICollectionView doesn't scroll after repopulate it

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode-storyboard

I've got a UICollectionView, with three buttons on the top to repopulate it (more popular items, closest items, recent items).

**My problem is that the scroll keeps the size of the first list, even when I repopulate it.
For example, if I have only one item on the first category (Selection) and I don't need to scroll when I click on the "A proximité" button and I have hundreds of items, it doesn't scroll...**

If the first category scroll, the other will scroll but with the size of the first category.

[image]
[image]

here is the code of how I populate the list

```
       self.restaurantList.removeAll()
       for restaurant in objects {
            self.restaurantList.append(restaurant!)
       }
       self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
       self.collectionView.reloadData()
             
    }
```

And here is the storyboard of my list
[image]

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: are you sure it scrolls fine with many items at first place? reload code seems fine

Comment: yes 100% sure...

Comment: that's my problem, let say at first the list needs to scroll for 10 items, if I change the list it keeps scrolling for maximum 10 items... even if there are more...

Comment: looks like the problem is inside your custom `AdaptiveSizeLayout`, please share its code